# Associative array to JSON

Tags: php, json, array-push

I would like to be able to generate a JSON output in the following format:

```
{"a":{"ax":1,"abx":2},"b":{"bax":1,"bbx":2},"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Although I have found that the respective code is this:

```
$arr = array('a' => array('ax' => 1, 'abx' => 2), 'b' => array('bax' => 1, 'bbx' => 2), 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
```

, I'm struggling to generate this output by using data from an SQL query. I have tried *array_push()* and *array_merge()* and the closest I have managed to get is this:

```
[{"a":{"ax":1,"abx":2}},{"b":{"bax":1,"bbx":2}}, ....]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: [Documentation: Read it. Love it. Use it.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

Comment: Are you asking how to get your SQL query results formatted like that PHP array, or are you asking about how to use `json_encode`?

Comment: Show your coding attempts. Did you try simply `$output["L"] = $sql_result;` instead of `array_push`?

Comment: Mmm, you get the array of rows from the database and then use json_encode on it. The question isn't very clear

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you should query all your data from the table and then move it to an array. After this, use the `json_encode($array)` function.

Place your array inside the parameters.

Then the output will be in JSON format.

```
$query = "select *  from employees";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $employee = $row['employee'];
  $country = $row['country'];

  $employees[] = array('employee'=> $employee, 'country'=> $country);
}

echo $jsonformat = json_encode($employees);
```

Answer (score 3):

Load the data you want encoded into an array, and then use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: OP presumably knows about that function. The question is about construing the `$arr` variable.

Comment: "OP presumably knows about that function." "Objection, Your Honor! Presuming facts not in evidence!" "Sustained."

Comment: Handcuffs! Send the convict into the manual prison. Unanimous jury decision!

Comment: My problem is that json_encode is introducing [] and it seems that they are interfering with my code. Is there any way to get rid of them?

Comment: It's valid JSON. If valid JSON is interfering with your code then you need to rethink what you are doing. There is probably a better way.