# json_encode() is not returning a json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to encode an associative array in php

```
$data = array(
        "firstName" => $_POST["firstName"],
        "lastName" => $_POST["lastName"],
        "email" => $_POST["email"],
        "telephone" => $_POST["telephone"]
);
```

however the output is in string format and not in array format.

```
string(98) "{"firstName":"rob","lastName":"shelford","email":"some@domain.co.uk","telephone":"01245454545"}"
```

The output needs to have the square brackets so the receiving server can read the data correctly.

Is there another syntax for the $data array I need to use?

EDIT 1

The offical PHP documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

states that

```
echo "Normal: ",  json_encode($a), "\n";
```

can be used to output

```
Normal: ["<foo>","'bar'","\"baz\"","&blong&","\u00e9"]
```

however when I try to use the `"\n"` flag, I receive an error

EDIT 2

The entire data I wish to convert

```
$data = array(
        "applicants" => array(
          "firstName" => $_POST["firstName"],
          "lastName" => $_POST["lastName"],
          "email" => $_POST["email"],
          "telephone" => $_POST["telephone"]
        ),
    "buyerType" => $_POST["buyerType"],
    "organisationId" => "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "introducerId" => "0",
    "introducerBranchId" => "0",
    "introducerNegotiatorId" => "0",
);
```

EDIT 3
I have made it work by passing this into json_encode() :

```
$data = array(

  "applicants"=> [
    array(
      "email"=> $_POST["email"],
      "firstName"=> $_POST["firstName"],
      "lastName"=> $_POST["lastName"],
      "telephone"=> $_POST["telephone"]
    )
  ],
  "buyerType" => $_POST["buyerType"],
  "organisationId" => "xxxxxxxxxx",
);
```

I have also removed the unnecessary lines in the above example

EDIT 4

The actual output I was expecting, and actually got, after implementing EDIT3

```
string(138) "{"applicants":[{"email":"some@domain.co.uk","firstName":"rob","lastName":"test","telephone":"01200000000"}],"buyerType":"Purchase"}"
```

Comment: Can you show the expected JSON string?

Comment: You encode your answer $json = json_encode($data); and the receiver decodes it $receiver = json_decode($json); to manipulate the object echo $receive->email; What is the problem?

Comment: Yes I can, 
{["firstName":"rob","lastName":"shelford","email":"design@wearenv.co.uk","telephone":"01245454545"]}
I think that is what is needed, I am new to json and php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Associative array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890107/associative-array-to-json)

Comment: I did see that before posting but its backwards to what I want. In that instance, the user is getting what I am expecting, but not what I am getting.

Comment: _{["firstName":"rob","lastName":"shelford","email":"design@wearenv.co.uk","telephone":"01245454545"]}_ This is not a valid json string.

Comment: If you want _[{"firstName":"rob","lastName":"shelford","email":"design@wearenv.co.uk","telephone":"01245454545"}]_, try `json_encode([$data]);`

Comment: I apologise if my wording is not correct, sometimes I find it difficult to articulate what is in my head.

Comment: @shingo Thankyou, I think this is what I was missing!!

Comment: @shingo This nearly works.. my actual live data includes a nested associative array, but using ([$data]) doesn’t put the square brackets around the nested array. How do I ensure the output is a nested array?

Comment: What do your data look like? I think the result of encoding [$data] is always surrounded by square brackets.

Comment: could you reply as an answer, I dont want to get flagged as a 'discussion' in this comment thread

Comment: You can update your question, add an example of your actual data and the expected result.

Comment: <?php $data = base64_decode('eyJhcHBsaWNhbnRzIjp7ImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6InRlc3QgZmlyc3ROYW1lIiwibGFzdE5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0IGxhc3ROYW1lIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0IGVtYWlsIiwidGVsZXBob25lIjoidGVzdCB0ZWxlcGhvbmUifSwiYnV5ZXJUeXBlIjoidGVzdCBidXllclR5cGUiLCJvcmdhbmlzYXRpb25JZCI6Inh4eHh4eHh4eHgiLCJpbnRyb2R1Y2VySWQiOiIwIiwiaW50cm9kdWNlckJyYW5jaElkIjoiMCIsImludHJvZHVjZXJOZWdvdGlhdG9ySWQiOiIwIn0=');
print_r($data);/* echo base64_encode(json_encode($data));   */   ?>     you can send safe the encoding(that function is meant to do that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want nested array to be encoded with square brackets surrounded, just put it in an array in php.

```
$data['applicants'] = [$data['applicants']];
echo json_encode($data);
```

FYI indexed array `[1,2]` will be encoded to json list `[1,2]`, and associative array `['x'=>1,'y'=>2]` will be encoded to json object `{"x":1,"y":1}`.